# What is wrong with this approach for transposing a matrix

Tags: python, list, sequences

Could anyone explain to me why is it wrong to tranpose a matrix using the following function:

```
def transpose(m):
    for row in range(len(m)):
        for col in range(len(m[0])):
            m[row][col] = m[col][row]
    return m

# example matrix:
m = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Python provides a handy function called zip for this.  It returns tuples by default, so you'll need to perform list comprehension over the result set to get a list of lists.

```
def transpose(m):
    return [list(x) for x in zip(*m)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that you need to swap elements. Say you want to swap item `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)`. But you just assign the value of `(2, 1)` to `(1, 2)` (you'll lose the value that was at `(1, 2)` thereby) and later you use the **new** value of `(1, 2)` to replace `(2, 1)`. That's why your approach won't give you the correct result. However you can swap elements:

```
def transpose(m):
    for row in range(len(m)):
        for col in range(row, len(m[0])):
            m[row][col], m[col][row] = m[col][row], m[row][col]  # swap
    return m
```

Note that `col` now starts with `row`-index, that's so you don't swap it twice (thereby defeating the purpose of transpose).

```
>>> transpose(m)
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Note: However if you intend to use it non-square matrices it will fail. In general `zip` or `np.transpose` should be favored. For example:

```
>>> list(map(list, zip(*m)))
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]

>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.transpose(m)
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```